# How do i update various roles in a table with different value using php pdo statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

My problem is i am trying to update multiple rows but i cant do it. i have tried using an update statment but it appears i am calling the rows wrongly.

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE wallet SET btc = :btc, usdt = :usdt, dodge = :dodge, xrp = :xrp, ltc = :ltc, eth = :eth, bnb = :bnb, solona = :solona "; 
            $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3); 
            $stmt3->execute(array( 
                ':btc' => $_POST['btc'], 
                ':usdt' => $_POST['usdt'],
                ':dodge' => $_POST['dodge'],
                ':xrp' => $_POST['xrp'], 
                ':ltc' => $_POST['ltc'],
                ':eth' => $_POST['eth'],
                ':bnb' => $_POST['bnb'],
                ':solona' => $_POST['solona']
            ));
```

| wallet_id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | btc | 34 |
| 2 | usdt | 42 |
| 3 | dodge | 42 |
| 4 | xrp | 42 |
| 5 | ltc | 42 |
| 6 | eth | 42 |
| 7 | bnb | 42 |
| 8 | solona | 42 |

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: You have no WHERE clause, how would the query know which rows to update?

Comment: post table and data, and show what exactly you try to update

Comment: We dont know which rows you want to update, using what criteria. But basically you need a WHERE clause to filter the target rows to your liking. This is basic SQL knowledge you should learn from any tutorial or course

Comment: i am new to stack over flow i am trying to add the table so you can better understand me

Comment: You've already been told what you need  to do. You need to add a `WHERE` clause to the query to specify which rows to update. This has nothing to do with PHP or PDO, you would need the same thing if you were running the SQL by hand.

Comment: if i add a where clause it will update a particular row i want all the rows at once

Comment: Thanks for the data. So...I think maybe you need to go on a basic SQL course for beginners, because this isn't even close to being correct. `btc` is not a column name, neither is `usdt`, or any of the others. In a `SET` clause the syntax is `column_name=value`. If you want to update one row in your table as you've shown it, it would be like `UPDATE wallet SET \`address\` = :value WHERE \`name\` = 'btc'`. Then to update a different row it would be `UPDATE wallet SET \`address\` = :value WHERE \`name\` = 'usdt'`....and so on...

Comment: You cannot easily update multiple different rows with different values, in a single UPDATE. You will need to execute several UPDATE statements targeting different rows, one for each different set of values you want to provide. Or perhaps you can use the CASE ... WHEN approach as Barmar has indicated below, although this is a lot less flexible if you then need to add different coin names in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have columns named `btc`, `dodge`, etc. Those are values in the `name` column. So the query should be like:

```
UPDATE wallet 
    SET address = CASE name
        WHEN 'btc' THEN :btc
        WHEN 'usdt' THEN :usdt
        ... -- repeat for all the different names
        ELSE address -- default to same value for unspecified names
    END
```